# raspotify/librespot disconnects immedately when Spotify Connect connects to it

Tags: raspberry-pi, spotify

I installed `raspotify` on my raspberry pi 3 as per [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-spotify/) hoping that my phone can use Spotify Connect to output to the speakers which are connected to the pi.

```
curl -sSL https://dtcooper.github.io/raspotify/key.asc | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/raspotify-archive-keyrings.asc >/dev/null
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/raspotify-archive-keyrings.asc] https://dtcooper.github.io/raspotify raspotify main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspotify.list
sudo apt install raspotify
```

This seems to have installed correctly.

By setting `LIBRESPOT_NAME="pi_spotify"` in `/etc/raspotify/conf` and rebooting the pi, I can go to Spotify on my phone, `Settings / Connect to a device`, and `pi_spotify` is available. Touching it, it seems to connect, as shown by this feedback at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

However, the playback pauses and no sound comes out. When I touch the play button, `@pi_spotify` seems to disconnect.

[image]

Sound on the pi otherwise works. If I ssh to it and `aplay /foo/bar.wav`, it plays through the speakers.

I found this via `journalctl --system | grep spotify`

```
Jan 17 09:45:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started raspotify.service - Raspotify (Spotify Connect Client).
Jan 17 09:45:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify-crash-report-generator.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 17 09:45:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Finished raspotify-crash-report-generator.service - Raspotify Crash Report Generator.
Jan 17 09:45:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify-crash-report-generator.service: Consumed 1.697s CPU time.
Jan 17 09:45:19 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:19Z WARN  librespot_core::apresolve] Ignoring blacklisted access point ap-gue1.spotify.com:4070
Jan 17 09:45:19 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:19Z WARN  librespot_core::apresolve] Ignoring blacklisted access point ap-gew4.spotify.com:443
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting raspotify-crash-report-generator.service - Raspotify Crash Report Generator...
```

I'm not sure how to read this exactly but naively taking the first two messages

```
Started raspotify.service - Raspotify (Spotify Connect Client).
raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify-crash-report-generator.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

it looks to me as if it is deactivating immediately after connecting.

I read somewhere to try `journalctl -u raspotify.service -b` and the output is a little different:

```
Jan 17 09:45:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started raspotify.service - Raspotify (Spotify Connect Client).
Jan 17 09:45:19 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:19Z WARN  librespot_core::apresolve] Ignoring blacklisted access point ap-gue1.spotify.com:4070
Jan 17 09:45:19 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:19Z WARN  librespot_core::apresolve] Ignoring blacklisted access point ap-gew4.spotify.com:443
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: Failed to get home directory.
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:20Z ERROR librespot_playback::player] Audio Sink Error Connection Refused: <AlsaSink> Device default May be Invalid, Busy, or Already in Use, ALSA>
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 17 09:45:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: raspotify.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
Jan 17 09:45:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started raspotify.service - Raspotify (Spotify Connect Client).
```

Here I notice

```
librespot[4364]: Failed to get home directory.
librespot[4364]: [2024-01-17T09:45:20Z ERROR librespot_playback::player] Audio Sink Error Connection Refused: <AlsaSink> Device default May be Invalid, Busy, or Already in Use, ALSA>
```

I don't know if these are related.

`speaker-test -t wav -c 2` when run on the pi produces the expected sounds on the connected speakers, so alsa works.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the default device. For me

`LIBRESPOT_DEVICE=hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0` in `/etc/conf`

resolved the issue.